# AngularJS App startup High Memory Usage

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, ionic-v1

My app react very weird. I don't really have any worker running or calling tremendous array data from server.

But my App run about 500MB at startup to first screen page and it is always 500MB not even reducing, and when I purposely press HOME button to go phone HOME screen, and go back to the my app again, the memory now reduced to 16MB. How is that even possible?

Ionic Info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.5
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS High Sierra
Node Version: v6.11.4
Xcode version: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Plugins

```
com.verso.cordova.clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.1 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.3.0 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.7.4 "Badges"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.19 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.7 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.2 "PushPlugin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Ok guys, it turns out was the Splash screen Problem.
I just change my splash screen format from 'Png' to 'psd' and the memory of startup greatly reduced